find elements in xArray by coordinate
I have a xArray like this
test = xr.DataArray([[0,1], [1, 2]], dims=['x', 'y'], coords={'x': [5, 6], 'y': [-7, -8]})

I want to get the position of the 1 by coordiantes.
I am expecting something like this,
[[5, -8], [6, -7]]
Thanks in advance for the help.

You can try this:
indices = np.where(test == 1)
indices_transposed = np.transpose(indices)

Then x and y will be lists with the unique x and y. You can list them together to get the outcome you wanted:
coords = [ [test[dim].values[ind] for dim, ind in zip(test.dims, index_pair)] for index_pair in indices_transposed]

This will return what you wanted.

Thanks a lot the quick reply. I ran this and gives me [5, 6], [-7, -8]. Which is not correct.

See the edits, I think this returns what you need. Not sure if there's a better way to obtain the coordinates without having to slice it like this.

yeah, I was doing something similar. Thanks for the answer.
